# jQuery how can i replace my links with input buttons

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my project : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Gh/2/)

In the menubar there are 3 links, which opens 3 different sub menus, each containing a close link.

When the links are hovered, they display the page url. To avoid this i would like to change the (links) into `<input>` buttons.

Html :

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="menu_f_si">
    <div id="middle_popup">
        <h1>Middle</h1>
        <p>Bla bla bla bla bla</p>
        <a href="#middle">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div id="right_popup">
         <h1>Right</h1>
         <p>Bla bla bla bla bla</p>
         <a href="#right">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div id="left_popup">
         <h1>Left</h1>
         <p>Bla bla bla bla bla</p>
         <a href="#left">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu_f_li">
    <ul id="menu_f_ll">
        <li><a href="#left">left menu</a></li>
        -
        <li><a href="#middle">middle menu</a></li>
        -
        <li><a href="#right">right menu</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(
 function()
 {$('#menu_f_ll li a').click(
   function(e)
   {e.preventDefault();
    animateSlider(this.hash);
   }
  );
  $('#menu_f_si div a').click(
   function(e)
   {e.preventDefault();
    animateSlider(this.hash);
   }
  );
  function animateSlider(hash)
  {if (!$('#menu_f_si div.open').length)
   {if (hash == '#middle') {openPopup(hash);}
    if (hash == '#right') {openPopup(hash);}
    if (hash == '#left') {openPopup(hash);}
   }
   else
   {if (hash == '#middle') {openAndClose(hash)}
    if (hash == '#right') {openAndClose(hash)}
    if (hash == '#left') {openAndClose(hash)}
   }
  }
  function openPopup(hash)
  {$(hash + '_popup').slideToggle().addClass('open');}
  function openAndClose(hash)
  {if ($(hash + '_popup').hasClass('open'))
   {$($(hash + '_popup')).slideToggle().removeClass();}
   else
   {$('#menu_f_si div.open').slideToggle().removeClass();
    $(hash + '_popup').slideToggle().addClass('open');
   }
  }
 }
);
```

I have been able to do so in other examples, but in this case the jQuery uses (hash) which i can't seem to imitate with `<input>`.

So my question is : Can i change the (links) into `<input>` buttons ? (And how)

Thank you for taking your time to help me :)

Comment: This is using a `button`, but should give you an idea of what you need to change to do what you want.  http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Gh/3/

Comment: It worked for hiding the url, but the close buttons doesnt work. Is data-hash like id? Where there can be only one?

Comment: _“When the links are hovered, they display the page url.”_ – and how is that a problem?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that, especially since its not leaving the page...

Comment: Thank you everyone... This place is AWESOME !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have Modified your code,

check this :

```
$('#menu_f_ll li input').click( //change here

function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    animateSlider($(this).attr('tabid')); //change here
});
$('#menu_f_si div input').click( //change here

function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    animateSlider($(this).attr('tabid')); //change here
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Gh/19/)**

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! But is it valid html to use href inside input??? That might sound stupid :)

Comment: you can change to any id say tabid, wait, will chage and update for you

Answer (score 1):

Just use some custom attribute instead of `href` for the `a`s.  Because you are using `href`, the browser decides to add the tooltip, but if you used some custom name like `menuid` and instead of using `this.hash` in your javascript, use `$(this).attr('menuid');`.

For the JavaScript:

```
animateSlider($(this).attr('menuid'));
```

instead of

```
animateSlider(this.hash);
```

and for the HTML:

```
<li><a menuid="#left">left menu</a></li>
```

instead of

```
<li><a href="#left">left menu</a></li>
```

This will eliminate the browser tooltip.  You will want to add some CSS to replace the hand cursor: `cursor: pointer;` to the `a`s.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqnkk/)

Comment: If i understand this correctly then the link is now using a (made up) attribute, which is pretty nice!

Comment: @DannyR.Thillemann, The whole point is to not use the `href` attribute as it is a special attribute telling the browser that this is a link to a new page.

Comment: I see... Thank you for spelling it out for me :)

Comment: @DannyR.Thillemann, Did this solve your problem, or is there something else?

Comment: This was perfect... Thank you SuperScript! I would vote this answer as useful, but i am new so i must wait for reputation 15 :)

Comment: @DannyR.Thillemann, You can just accept my answer if it is the best solution (by clicking on the empty check mark).

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Gh/7/ removing all links.

Get the menu to open by using data attributes and use classes instead of elements to bind click events.

With CSS, you can use `cursor: pointer` to indicate that the `li` and close span are clickable.